# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Despite the many, many tutorials I have searched through, the dropdown feature of my navigation bar is not functioning.  Please help if you know some sort of difference with multidimensional dropdown menus in Bootstrap 3 that I am not seeing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Schedule</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Day One</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Day Two</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Day Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div><button style="margin-left: 5px;" class="btn btn-default" type=
      "submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of things going on with your file:

- Your doctype is wrong. You're specifying XHTML 1.0, when you should be just using the HTML5 declaration.
- As @sbat pointed out above, you're missing the Bootstrap script file.

I've completely formatted your template below, per the usual tutorials. Let me know if you have any questions or need anything else.

**UPDATE**: Here's link to your menu in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su3T6/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Bootstrap Menu Sample</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="Aahan Krish's Blog - Homepage">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Artists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Art</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Schedule <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu unstyled pull-left dropdown-features">
                    <li><a href="#">Day One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Day Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Day Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Venue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do realize the dropdown functionality (and several other features) requires Bootstrap's JS file right (which in turn requires jQuery)? I don't see a reference to it, you could try adding these script tags at the bottom of your body tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```